# How can I get the data of an object in datatables?

Tags: symfony, oop, object, datatables, twig

I am getting data from a json file into my datatable.

```
"columns": [
  {% for key, value in columns %}
    {
    "data": "{{ key }}"},
    {% endfor %}
]
```

Like this I get the following output:

```
id  name            slug      icon  
2   Mitarbeiter     members   [object Object]   
3   Angebote        offers    [object Object]   
4   Produkte        products  [object Object]   
5   Felder          fields    [object Object]
```

To recieve the data of the object, I changed my code to this:

```
"columns": [
      {% for key, value in columns %}
      {   "data": "{{ key }}.name",
      "defaultContent": "{{ key }}"},
      {% endfor %}
    ]
```

This is working well for the object, but now my other fields do not show the value anymore, the show the label of the column:

```
id  name    slug    icon 
id  name    slug    icon    
id  name    slug    anchor  
id  name    slug    adjust  
id  name    slug    cloud
```

---

dump of columns:

```
array:5 [▼
  "id" => ReflectionProperty {#6092 ▶}
  "name" => ReflectionProperty {#6094 ▶}
  "slug" => ReflectionProperty {#6096 ▶}
  "icon" => ReflectionProperty {#6097 ▶}
]
```

---

Another approach is this:

```
   "columns": [
      {% for key, value in columns %}
      {% if key is iterable %}
      {"data": "{{ key }}"},
      {% else %}
      {"data": "{{ key }}.name"},
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    ]
```

But here I get only the output of the `icons` row...

---

The json file is this:

```
[{"id":2,"name":"Mitarbeiter","icon":{"id":2,"name":"anchor"},"slug":"members"},{"id":3,"name":"Angebote","icon":{"id":1,"name":"adjust"},"slug":"offers"},{"id":4,"name":"Produkte","icon":{"id":1,"name":"adjust"},"slug":"products"},{"id":5,"name":"Felder","icon":{"id":1,"name":"cloud"},"slug":"fields"}]
```

Comment: @DarkBee This did not work out unfortunately

Comment: Then update the existing question with new information...

Comment: @DarkBee I decided to write it new, otherwise this would be confusing

Comment: How are you feeding your columns to `twig`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution:

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        "render": function (data, type, row) {
          var type = typeof data;
          if(type == "object"){
            return data.name;
          } else {
            return data;
          }

        },
        "targets": "_all"
      }
    ],
"columns": [
     {% for key, value in columns %}
     {   "data": "{{ key }}"},
     {% endfor %}
   ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Truy to use: of_type('object')

```
"columns": [
    {% for key, value in columns %}
        {
            "data": "{% if key is of_type('object') %}{{ key }}.name{% else %}{{ key }}{% endif %}"},
    {% endfor %}
    { "data": "id" }
]
```

Comment: I tested your code. The error message is `Unknown "of_type" test.`

Comment: Are you using this plugin? https://github.com/victor-sm/Craft-TwigTypeTest